# Switchable Graphics: Embeded graphics card problems

Tags: 12.04, ati, 64-bit, hybrid-graphics

I have a **Dell Inspirion 17R 5721** It has a AMD graphics card and a Intel. I installed the drivers that AMD develops and I ran into the following problems.

1. Every time it's me that has to change the card from Intel To AMD and vice versa.
2. When I'm using Intel... Graphics don't actually work. The error I'm getting from a game when I run it is this:

   ```
   ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.2.34167/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
   ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.2.34167/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

   ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.2.34167/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
   ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/deus/Programs/Phoenix_Firestorm-Release_i686_4.4.2.34167/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
   ```

What I understand from this is that some libraries couldn't be loaded?
But why does it work when I'm using AMD's card and not when I use Intels?

Before AMD put out drivers for my graphics card in linux, I used Intel graphics card and it worked.

Since Discrete graphics are not well supported (talking about crazy fan speed and heat problems) I want to use only Intel's graphic card and keep discrete deactivated.

Any ideas on how to make Intel run my game again and keep discrete card from running (freaking fan drivers me crazy) when I use linux?

Comment: How do you switch these cards? I have exactly same GFX cards on my laptop to reproduce this issue , can you please provide me steps that you followed to install and switch these cards?

Comment: The way I'm supposed to. Open catalyst control center and select INTEL graphics then restart.

Comment: And how can i install that tool?

Comment: I don't want to come across as rude. But if you haven't even installed the drivers for AMD card, what are the chances that you will solve my problem? http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64 Download and install. Then you'll find it in dash.

Comment: Because , i am using both cards and they work for me without any problem. I am trying to figure out why they are not working for you. If i know your method, i can figure out why its not working. I apologize if you didn't like my approach.

Comment: Also, which Ubuntu version you are running?

Comment: I did something, hope it helps -)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for persisting on this, even if I could seem to be rude. Secondly, I'm using 12.04. Thirdly, Thank you. :)

Comment: I am using 13.04 and it works flawless for me. You can try to install latest graphic drivers from amd and upgrade to 13.04 or 13.10.

Comment: The thing is that 12.04 is stable and I like stable. Even with this version... I had to re-install many times until I got it the way I wanted it. I tried to upgrade once, and that was a disaster. So staying in 12.04

Comment: 13.04 is stable for me. I am avid Ubuntu user.I have yet to see more stable version that 13.04

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the AMD card, follow this [link](http://planetoss.com/articles/how-to-disable-the-discrete-amd-graphics-card-in-linux/)

Also you may want to uninstall the proprietary drivers :`sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`

Comment: I think the `vgaswitcheroo` method to disable the AMD card only works if you are using the open source radeon drivers, not the proprietary AMD fglrx drivers?